# Javascript regex: Convert Emojione img to shortname

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var test = '<img class="emojione" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.4/assets/png/1f600.png?v=2.2.5" alt=":grinning:" /><img class="emojione" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.4/assets/png/1f621.png" alt=":rage:" />';
test = test.replace(/<img.*?class="emojione".*?alt="(.*)?".*?>/g, '$1');
console.log(test);
```

Help me on javascript regex. I want the output to be ":grinning::rage:". This regex only works if there is only one img

Comment: change `(.*)?` to `(.*?)`

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work i think :

```
/<img.*?class="emojione".*?alt="(.*?)".*?>/g
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/fU9rA7/1)

Here's a [working example](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/AblazeSoaringPotatoEvita).